# Select values in Pandas groupby dataframe that are present in n previous groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a Pandas dataframe `groupby` object which looks like the following:

```
        ID
2014-11-30  1   
        2
        3
2014-12-31  1   
        2
        3
        4
2015-01-31  2   
        3
        4
2015-02-28  1   
        3
        4
        5
2015-03-31  1   
        2
        4
        5
        6
2015-04-30  3   
        4
        5
        6
```

What I want to do is create another dataframe where the values in groupby date x are values that are in each of groupby dates y(x-1) thru y(x-n) where y is the n period previous groupby.  So for instance, if n=1, then if x groupby period is '2015-04-30', then you would check against '2015-03-31'.  If n=2, then if groupby date '2015-02-28', then you would check against groupby dates ['2015-01-31', '2014-12-31'].

The resulting dataframe from the above would look like this for n=1:

```
        ID
2014-12-31  1   
        2
        3
2015-01-31  2   
        3
        4
2015-02-28  3   
        4
2015-03-31  1   
        4
        5
2015-04-30  4   
        5
        6
```

The resulting dataframe for n=2 would be:

```
2015-01-31  2   
        3
2015-02-28  3   
        4
2015-03-31  4   
2015-04-30  4   
        5
```

Looking forward to some pythonic solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to work:

```
def filter_unique(df, n):
    data_by_date = df.groupby('date')['ID'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())

    filtered_data = {}
    previous = []
    for i, (date, data) in enumerate(data_by_date.items()):
        if i >= n:
            if len(previous)==1:
                filtered_data[date] = list(set(previous[i-n]).intersection(data))
            else:
                filtered_data[date] = list(set.intersection(*[set(x) for x in previous[i-n:]]).intersection(data))
        else:
            filtered_data[date] = data
        previous.append(data)

    result =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(filtered_data, orient='index').stack()
    result.index = result.index.droplevel(1)

filter_unique(df, 2)

1/31/15     2
1/31/15     3
1/31/15     4
11/30/14    1
11/30/14    2
11/30/14    3
12/31/14    2
12/31/14    3
2/28/15     1
2/28/15     3
3/31/15     1
3/31/15     4
4/30/15     4
4/30/15     5
```

Comment: this does work so thank you.  I think there is probably a more efficient way.  Will keep my eyes open for one.  THanks again.